# Calling one R Installation from Another

Tags: r

I seem to be unable to compile RPostgreSQL for Windows x64, and after extensive searching, I've not been able to find a precompiled binary.  To get on with my work, I've installed a 32 bit version of Postgre and have been using 32 bit R for all database ops.

I need to do much of my work in 64 bit R, so switching back and forth has become a bit painful, especially since this requires a save() and load() operation each time I need to run a query.

I'm wondering whether it is possible to call one R installation directly from another?  For example, could I simply pass queries to my 32 bit R installation and retrieve the result?  I think there are other times when the ability to call another R installation would be useful as well.

All I've come up with is using a system() call, either directly to pgsql or to 32-bit R, but this doesn't allow for very efficient transfer of data.

I'd **very sincerely appreciate** any advice or assistance!

P.S. I'd rather ask how to compile RPostgreSQL for x64, but as I understand the rules here, such a question would be inappropriate since it's not a general question (e.g. I'd need step-by-step instructions since I don't have the requisite skills).

Comment: Speaking as one of several people contributing to RPostgreSQL, we could do with a knowledgeable person dealing with Windows, 32 and 64.  But yes, you may have to build PostgreSQL first.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, for RPostgreSQL and for the many other contributions you've made - they are deeply appreciated.  As for compiling, the process can be very mysterious to those of us who live in interpreted languages!

Comment: see comment here: http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/r-release/ReadMe  so install.packages('RPostgreSQL', type='source') might just work if you are set up to build R packages from source and your DB is available

Comment: Thanks mdsummer.  I was finally able to install from source successfully by following those directions.  Now I can load RPostgreSQL and get a db driver with dbDriver(), but R crashes whenever I try to create a connection with dbConnect().  Since it seems to compile correctly, I'm pretty much at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/64bit_Windows_port