# RODBC trying to speed up saveSQL

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I am trying to use a function I found here to speed up saveSql, because its so painfully slow with large data sets.

The function is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708719/improving-rodbc-postgres-write-performance)

I always get an error that the object was not found using my sqlQuery

```
sqlQuery(channel, paste("COPY ", TEST, " FROM '", getwd(), "/", TEST, ".csv' WITH NULL AS 'NA' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;",sep=""))

**object 'TEST' not found**
```

The rest of the code is working.

Comment: What's the question here, speed optimization or that error message?

Comment: That error message, why SQL cant find TEST. I created the table TEST and TEST.csv exist. Also the SQL server can access the directory.

Comment: Please edit your message to reflect your title. Try avoiding several different questions in one post.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the bit about `sqlQuery`, just look at the call to `paste`.  R expects a variable named `TEST`, presumably containing a string.

```
TEST <- "test"
paste("COPY ", TEST, " FROM '", getwd(), "/", TEST, ".csv' WITH NULL AS 'NA' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;",sep="")
```

Comment: getting me a bit closer, but now i got `"42000 156 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]`and `"42000 319[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]`

Comment: @user2963882 I'm not convinced that the resulting string is valid T-SQL.  If you want to speed up writing files to SQL server, you could try calling `RODBC:::sqlwrite` directly, or trying the `RSqlServer` package instead. `library(devtools); install_github("RSqlServer", "agstudy")` (Some dependencies required.)